# In VSCode, how to add a new selection to the document via the API?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trying to write my first VSCode extension and I'm stuck on a simple issue. I've built a new Selection via something like

```
var new_sel = new Selection(start, end);
```

where `start` and `end` are `vscode.Position` objects. Now I'd like to add this as a selection to my document, but I'm pretty lost. I'm inside `vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand` command so I have access to a `TextEditor` and to a `TextEditorEdit` objects and all their fields, but I don't see anything in the API about adding/subtracting selections from a document.

How do I add a selection, so that it's reflected in `TextEditor.selections`? (I tried to simply push it to that array, but I got a "debugger attached" error in the console.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick:

```
let mySelections: vscode.Selection[] = [];
let line1 = 12, char1 = 5, line2 = 20, char2 = 3;  //Just some examples.
let line3 = 29, char3 = 3, line4 = 26, char4 = 7;  //Just some examples.

mySelections.push(line1, char1, line2, char2);
mySelections.push(line3, char3, line4, char4);
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selections = mySelections;
```

Answer (score -1):

The `TextEditor.selections` can simply be overwritten.

Beware, however, trying to `pop` or `push` onto `TextEditor.selections` didn't work for me.